# Why is NewtonSoft not able to parse this json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

When I go to online [viewers](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/), this shows as legal `JSON`,

```
stringstuff =  "[
  {
    "data": {
      "user": {
        "email": "john@doe.com",
        "external-id": "47b4-af36-e9fddecdb755"
      },
      "session-token": "BNIYdxZZew5KWnKHNZMjn8J3Q-Ii2q7Ifcs5klkginluGHhEalz-uA+C"
    },
    "context": "/sessions"
  }
]";
```

but fails when I try

```
var jtoken = JObject.Parse(stringStuff)
```

with `Exception`:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)
   at TastyWorksAPI.URLGetRestValues.<Authorize>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\synct\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\API\API.cs:line 61
```

Comment: You can help others help you by editing your question to show the exact error message you got. Also, try cutting out the elements of the JSON content one by one -- perhaps you will find that there is one element which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string contains a json array, but you are trying to parse it as object, use `JToken.Parse` or `JArray.Parse`:

```cs
var jtoken = JArray.Parse(stringStuff);
```